# Socket.io 1.3.7 ignoring options

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I have a node.js script that when a client connects reads and dumps the contents of a Mongo DB. I've just upgraded from socket.io 0.9 and the lack of examples & poor [docs](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#) have left me somewhat confused.

I used to be able to set options using `io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling'])` but this has been removed, from what I can work out the new way to define options is like this

```
        {
        allowUpgrades: false,
        transports: [ 'polling' ],
        pingTimeout: 5000,
        pingInterval: 2500
        };
```

But... They appear to be being ignored.

Here is the full node.js script;

```
var io = require('socket.io')(8002, options);
cp = require('child_process');
var tail = cp.spawn('test-scripts/k-test.rb');
    var options = {
        allowUpgrades: false,
        transports: [ 'polling' ],
        pingTimeout: 5000,
        pingInterval: 2500
        };

    //On connection do the code below//
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log();


        //Read the state list from db//
        var connection_string = '127.0.0.1:27017/test';
        var mongojs = require('mongojs');
        var db = mongojs(connection_string, ['k1']);
        var k1 = db.collection('k1');
        db.k1.find({}, {'_id': 0, "data.time":0}).forEach(function(err, doc) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (doc) { io.emit('k1', doc); }
            });
```

When a client connects it still gets upgraded to a web-socket connection rather than staying as a polling session. The `pingTimeout` & `pingInterval` don't work - if I connect from a mobile client it takes at least 1 min from the time I close the browser to the time the server says the client has timed out.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please as to where I'm going wrong. I can provide the old (0.9) code if it's any help.

**Update**:
Fixed with answer from @mscdex below. A helpful note for anyone else - if you have debug enabled then when the options are being read at start-up you should get an output like this; `socket.io:server creating engine.io instance with opts {"allowUpgrades":false,"transports":["polling"],"pingTimeout":10000,"pingInterval":5000,"path":"/socket.io"} +9ms`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use `options` before it is actually set. Variables themselves *are* hoisted in JavaScript, but their assignments like that are not. This means you are actually passing in `undefined` (which probably causes defaults to be loaded) instead of your `options` object.

The solution is to set `options` before you reference it. For example:

```
var options = {
    allowUpgrades: false,
    transports: [ 'polling' ],
    pingTimeout: 5000,
    pingInterval: 2500
};
var io = require('socket.io')(8002, options);

// ...
```

Comment: Ha! foiled by something so simple as that. Thank you so much just tested & its working :-)